# Generating c++ Code from *.slx

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulation, simulink

I have a question regarding generating C++ code from a Simulink diagrams (*.slx file). I know that one could generate c/c++ and header files using Simulink Coder toolbox. Is there any other way to generate c/c++ file from a Simulink diagrams? Maybe Embedded Coder?(I have tested `codegen`, but does not work, since it generate c++ code from an M-file)

Comment: Could you explain why you don't use the Simulink Coder? `codegen` is a Matlab Coder command, not a Embedded Coder command. To generate code from a Simulink Model you have the choice between Simulink Coder, Embedded Coder and dSPACE TargetLink (3rd Party Software) and maybe other alternatives I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any license to use it! :(

Comment: Embedded Coder is an add-on to Simulink Coder, so you can't use it if you don't have a license for Simulink Coder in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get a license for the Simulink Coder. You may take a look at the alternatives I mentioned in my comment, but as long as the Simulink Coder satisfies your requirements, it's the cheapest option.